# Get phone number from href and transform them, on desktop and mobile devices

Tags: php, wordpress

Get phone number from `href` and transform them, on desktop and mobile devices

```
123.456.789 | 123.456.789
```

This type of phone number is in one text line on the front end.
I want to transform both numbers individually, without dashes or dots.

How can I use anchor tag `href` to fetch both numbers individually?

Comment: What do you mean by redirect?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to remove dot from your phone number string then use code something like that as I explained below.

```
<?php 
$phone_no = '123.456.789';
$phone = str_replace(".", "", $phone_no);
?>

 <a href="tel:<?php echo $phone ?>"><?php echo $phone_no ?></a> | <a href="tel:<?php echo  $phone ?>"><?php echo $phone_no ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to also remove that dash from this 2 numbers and redirect both numbers individually.

Comment: I get that numbers to frontent in only one line

Comment: Ok.., so.. add another line like: `$phone = str_replace("-", "", $phone_no);`
Of course there are ways to also do this in 1 statement.  But keeping it simple, the above line is easy to infer from Anas's solution.
BTW, your example question does not show any dashes.

Answer (score -1):

Use this Code

```
<a href="tel:123456789">123.456.789</a> | <a href="tel:123456789">123.456.789</a>
```

Comment: I can't do this bcz its written in one line from backend site in wordpress.

Comment: Also, this does not answer the question.  That is rewriting the HTML.  OP has access to HTML, and must extract the data *from* HTML, and transform it, using PHP, into a format he can use elsewhere in his PHP code.